# Parallax effect of image

Tags: javascript, parallax

I am currently trying to create a parallax movement of an image while moving the mouse on the screen in javaScript. To do this I have managed to create the following code:

```
var mainImage = document.getElementById("mainLogo");
var currentX = '';
var currentY = '';
var movementConst = .5;

function moveMainImage(event)
{
    if (currentX = '') currentX = event.screenX;
    var diffX = event.screenX - currentX;
    currentX = event.screenX;
    if (currentY = '') currentY = event.screenY;
    var diffY = event.screenY - currentY;
    currentY = event.screenY;

    var movementX = diffX * movementConst;
    var movementY = diffY * movementConst;
    var newX = mainImage.style.left + movementX;
    var newY = mainImage.style.top + movementY;

    mainImage.style.left = newX + "px";
    mainImage.style.top = newY + "px";
}

document.addEventListener("mousemove", moveMainImage);
```

The problem that I am having is that the "mousemove" event listener is only happening once and not called each time that there is mouse movement. I am still pretty new at javaScript so I apologize if this is a simple question. Please help??

Comment: It would definitely be called multiple times just from that code snippet, so there's something else going on that we can't tell from what you've given us

Comment: `mainImage.style.left` will be a string: something like `540px` and so `mainImage.style.left + movementX` will be a weird concatenated string like `540px12` rather than an addition.  You can use `parseFloat` to turn `mainImage.style.left` into a number. because: `parseFloat('12.34px') == 12.34`